# Quick way to replace all occurences of a value in a pandas data frame with NA

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a python script to clean and concatenate a number of large .csv files. Specifically, I'm reading the files in using the pandas read_csv function and then dealing with them as dataframe objects, which was been working great. This is my first time using pandas, so I'm still getting used to all of the incredibly helpful functions that it includes.

The csv files that I'm reading in use -99.9 as a sentinel value to indicate NA/NaN. Since this is different than the way that I'm denoting missing data elsewhere, I'd like to change all occurrences of -99.9 to "NaN". Is there a quick built in way to do that, or do I have to iterate over the dataframe and check each value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can do that when you use the read_csv method.   Just add parameter

```
na_values=-99.9
```

as parameter of read_csv method.  Check full documentation

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks! The only change I had to make was making -99.9 a string and putting it in a list (i.e. ["-99.9"]).

Answer (score 3):

I think @Joop's response is more elegant. However, if you find that there are certain other values that should be replaced by `NA/NaN`, after reading in the CSV, then you can use:

```
pandas_dataframe.replace(['bad_data_1', 'bad_data_2'], [None, None], inplace=True)
```

Set inplace to `False` if you want to create a separate dataframe.

And if you know the bad values while reading the CSV, then modifying @Joop's response to include the list as:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('/my.csv', na_values=["bad_value_1", "bad_value_2"])
```